# Tag : tor-messenger

Tags: discussion, tags

Can anyone make a tor-messenger tag. Due to absence of it I have to tag my question to **tor-bundle** and some other random tags which make them irrelevant.

Comment: I've added the tag to [your question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/16673/88). So now the tag exists throughout the site.